# Android app webservice pull data back to server database

Tags: java, android, sql, web-services, pull

I have an android app and I would like to pull data from the app to a server database using a webservice. How can I do that?

Comment: with http requests :)

Answer (score 0):

you should look for tutorials on webservices in android with JSON

read about JSON if you don't know about it

good luck.

Comment: I don't think "you should look for an tutorial" is really an answer, even if the suggestion about JSON is helpful. Ideally you'd explain why JSON is the right choice and provide a tutorial link with your own summary.

Comment: that is the only information that I can provide , perhaps to induce doubt about Android+JSON. It's a begining